# OpenCV - How to identify multiple unknown images inside a larger image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Template matching doesn't work here I don't think because the smaller images are unknown, so I was thinking using contour detection, but it seems to be picking up too much noise and not the exact contour of the images. This is my code so far:

```
img = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img2, contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, 
method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

image_copy = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image=image_copy, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", image_copy)
```

This is the input image:

[image: input]

This is what Im currently getting:

[image: bad output]

This would be the ideal output:

[image: ideal output]

Comment: Is your background always supposed to be blue?

Comment: @Farshid the background and foreground little images can be anything, that makes it more tricky

Comment: The hardest part is to separate the overlapping/side by side parts. The rest is doable using different sequences of morphologyEx function. I am thinking of a neural network based segmentation.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out ? I'm trying to do the same thing, but can't really manage. Using pre-trained models, it usually detects object inside images, not images itself.